# logger.setLevel doesn't return desired level

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to use this code in my app:

```
 def logger(log_file='base.log', set_level='INFO', identity='base'):
     set_level = get_settings().logging_setLevel
     if log_file:
         log_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '/mnt/logs/')
         if not os.path.exists(log_path):
             os.makedirs(log_path)
         handler = logging.FileHandler(log_path+log_file)
     else:
         handler = logging.StreamHandler()

     formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - '+ identity +' - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
     handler.setFormatter(formatter)
     logger = logging.getLogger(identity)
     logger.addHandler(handler)
     logger.setLevel(eval("logging." + set_level))

     return logger
```

But the problem is regardless what level I choose in `set_level` argument it still produces all levels ('DEBUG' and so on....).

Can you please help me identify the problem.

Comment: You should probably use `getattr` instead of `eval` to get the level from `logging`, as `eval` could allow someone to execute pretty much any arbitrary code they want just but putting it in your config file.  It will also be easier to handle exceptions for bad error levels that way.  Also, evaluating that statement won't give you a string anyway, it's basically a noop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `eval`, try this:

```
level = logging.getLevelName(set_level)
logger.setLevel(level)
```

Comment: will give it a shot in a moment

Comment: No, it didn't help =( still the same

Comment: @Vor ok, I've commented out `set_level = get_settings().logging_setLevel` line and it works for me. Why are you redefining `set_level` in the function?

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I completely forgot about this! ))) You are right.